# Invalid result for Order By in postgresql

Tags: sql-order-by, postgresql-9.3

I was trying to order a table "main_table" by date (which is a float), my initial table looks like this (`select date from main_table`):

```
      date
 20160424105948
 20160424045955
 20160424050000
 20160418170003
 20160419233154
 20160419233155
```

so by creating another table with ordered rows by "Order by date", i get some rows which are not correctly ordered:

```
create temp table tmp (like main_table including defaults);
insert into tmp (select * from compact_table order by date asc)
```

and it i get (`select date from tmp`) :

```
      date
 20160418170908
 20160418170909
 20160418170910
 20160420110031 <<
 20160418170911
```

'date' is a primary key, and i have up to 600000 rows in my table, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted. Your select statement has no `order by` and therefor the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes. The ***ONLY*** way to get a sorted result is to use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: And why on earth are you storing a `date` in a `float` column? That is a **really** bad idea.

Comment: Actually i'm importing data from csv files,the dates in theses files are not well formatted so i'm preparing the dates format (and i cast them in floats) in python script before inserting them in my table.
And when i'm importing my tmp table into a csv file i'm not getting the right order (By using copy_to from psycopg2 lib) , so it means that my "tmp" table is not ordered right ?.

Comment: Again: rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "ordered". Neither your `main_table` nor your `tmp` table (or any other table) as an implicit "order". If you want a specific sort order you have to use `order by` in your query that displays the data.

Comment: Oh, ok then, i thought we could order a table but the displaying of results by select is random. I think that for my case i'll need using copy_expert to specify the select query with the right Order by.
I'm very new to sql queries, thank you for your time.
Thanks again.
i'll update this post with a solution for my issue, hope it could help.